# Get and Post vs Query String

Tags: asp.net

Whenever we redirect from one page to another page, Query string can be used. Now when i used the "GET" and "POST" methods in the form tag.

I have got the following findings.

1. Get - Exposes is the data of password fields in the URL. SO it should not be used. Right?
2. POST - Some unnecessary data can be accessed from Request .Form of the textbox fields which is not required.

I think, while navigating to another page, I can use Query String on clikcing the button like below.

```
Response.Redirect("abc.aspx?id=10") //This will be at the code behind level.
```

and similarly we can use in Java Script like below.

```
function RedirecToAnotherPage(){
    window.open('abc.aspx?id=10');}
```

Right?

Here, my query is in which case, I can use the "GET" and "Post" method in real life/dynamic website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`POST` removes constraints that `GET` has, like maximum query string size.  You can control what data is sent by controlling which fields are inside the form tag.  You can have multiple form tags and post the relevant one.

Comment: I can have only one server tag, As i have only server controls. what will happen if i have 30-40 textboxes in a form and "POST" is used. Another issue is I have label control, this contains text in the form of id and is hidden control. If this information is to be passed then it will pass only textbox info right? So both can be avoided in this case. Query string can be used only?

Comment: If you want to use the same form for different posts, you can use javascript to update the 'action' attribute (eg. update/insert)

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are creating a secure website you should use POST method
2. If you are sending a big and bulky datum to a server you have to use post because GET has some limitation.
3. In case of URL rewriting or you are developing website where you have to use SEO in that case your URL plays an important role; in that situation you should use GET.
4. GET is faster than POST

Comment: Item #4 is practically nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose [GET](http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/Axioms.html#state) method especially when you want to read and choose `POST` when you want to write/update (database or file etc). Take a look at article  - [Methods GET and POST in HTML forms - what's the difference?](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html)

To learn more on ASP.NET web-app Forms.

1. [How to: Post ASP.NET Web Pages to a Different Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140.aspx).
2. [ASP.NET Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163736.aspx).

Comment: @StackOverflowUser - What kind of links? Form methods will be same for different technologies.

Comment: @StackOverflowUser I'd recommend understanding the basic ideas of HTML forms before you work with ASP.Net. You're trying to build a house without a foundation.