# Can i pass web method parameter like query string?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Here i am using a webmethod 'InsertData'.  Can I pass parameters like query `string["json.aspx/InsertData?username="+name+"......"]` instead of passing as `data`? Is there any advantages if I use like query string.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
        url: "json.aspx/InsertData",
        data: "{'username':'" + name + "','subj':'" + subject + "','desc':'" + body + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
                 var obj = data.d;
                 if (obj == 'true') {
                       $('#txtname').val('');
                       $('#txtsubject').val('');
                       $('#txtbody').val('');
                       $('#lblmsg').html("Details Submitted Successfully");
                 }
        },
        error: function(result) {
                 alert("Error");
        }
});
```

Comment: why do you need to pass it as query paramerters , any specific reason?

Comment: i want to know is there any way or not , to ease my url encryption and also to know which one is more advantageous?

Comment: @dreamweiver no more specific reason but why don't we use like query string?

Comment: Does it work your solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm thinking in 2 disavantages:

1. If you pass data using query string, the data is visible in the browser URL
2. The URL have some length limitation depending on web server, so if you put a lot of data in the URL the server may reject your request. IIS returns a 404.14 if `Request Limits` is exceed by the lenght of URL.

To pass a query string to Webmethod do the following:

- You have to set up the URL with the query string parameters
- You have to get this parameters at server side getting them from `Request` object.

**client side**

```
var url = "json.aspx/InsertData?username=" + name + "&subj=" + subject + "&desc=" + body;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
             var obj = data.d;
             if (obj == 'true') {
                   $('#txtname').val('');
                   $('#txtsubject').val('');
                   $('#txtbody').val('');
                   $('#lblmsg').html("Details Submitted Successfully");
             }
    },
    error: function(result) {
             alert("Error");
    }
   });
```

At the server side you have to inspect the `Request` object:

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
    public static object InsertData()
    {
         var name = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["username"];
         var subject = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["subject"];
         var desc = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["desc"];

         // Do some work
    }
```

Comment: Thank you  @anmarti for this code with detailed explanation,i was thinking thinking about these what will be the dis advantages too.. thank you so much .

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514986/get-and-post-vs-query-string

Comment: Thank you @anmarti,got an idea