# How can I pass parameters in javascript fetch call

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm integrating Stripe payments in an aspx site (VB, .NET 4.7.2).
I took Javascripts from Stripe samples.
I try to call this method of the backend:

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function CreateStripePaymentIntent(ByVal aPrice As String) As PaymentIntent
    ...
End Function
```

from a Javascript in the page:
(here the parameter is a fixed value, to simplify)

```
fetch("PayOrder.aspx/CreateStripePaymentIntent?aPrice=111", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',                                   
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  body: JSON.stringify(purchase)
})
```

If I remove the parameter all works well (but is useless).
If I try to pass the parameter I always have error 500:
POST http://localhost:14987/PayOrder.aspx/CreateStripePaymentIntent?aPrice=111
Status 500
Internal Server Error
Version HTTP/1.1
Transferred 0,98 kB (660 B size)
Referrer Policy strict-origin-when-cross-origin

**Message   "No value for parameter 'aPrice'."** (my translation from italian to english!)

Someone can tell me WHY this parameter does not reach the backend?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can i pass web method parameter like query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235252/can-i-pass-web-method-parameter-like-query-string)

Comment: If you're sending parameter in query string then what's in the body?

Answer (score 1):

The values are sent in the request body, in the format that the content type specifies.

Usually the content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded, so the request body uses the same format as the query string:

```
parameter=value&also=another
```

When you use a file upload in the form, you use the multipart/form-data encoding instead, which has a different format. It's more complicated, but you usually don't need to care what it looks like, so I won't show an example, but it can be good to know that it exists.

for Json content type is application/json

```
fetch("PayOrder.aspx/CreateStripePaymentIntent", {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ aPrice: 111 })
})
```